# Replace with RegEx and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, theory, replace

I am attempting to do a quick replace of the 'innerHTML' of the 'code' element.  I thought this may work:

```
function codeDisplay ( ) {
    var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML;

    var codeExam1 = new RegExp('<', 'gm');
    var codeExam2 = new RegExp('>', 'gm');

    code.replace(codeExam1, '&lt;');
    code.replace(codeExam2, '&gt;');
      }
```

Do I need to perform any additional steps to push the information back to the browser or conversion of data types maybe?  Or am I completely wrong in how 'RegEx' and 'innerHTML' work?  I appreciate the feedback in advance.

Comment: Am I missing something or is regex for this like using a sledgehammer on a finish nail?

Comment: You probably want to write `code = code.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')` as well -- even before the `<` and `>` steps.

Comment: @BradChristie - How else would you do it? String replacement only finds the very first one. Do you really think `code.split('>').join('&gt;')` is any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first fo all:

```
var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML;
```

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a list of *elements* not just one. So, if your purpose is escaping *all* the `code` tags you have in the page, you need to iterate them.
Second, I believe you can avoid regexp just using `textContent` (where supported) or `innerText`.

```
var codes = document.getElementsByTagName("code");

for (var i = 0, code; code = codes[i++];) {
    if ("textContent" in code)
        code.textContent = code.innerHTML;
    else if ("innerText" in code)
        code.innerText = code.innerHTML;
}
```

or create a new text node:

```
var codes = document.getElementsByTagName("code");

for (var i = 0, code, html; code = codes[i++];) {
    html = code.innerHTML;

    code.innerHTML = "";

    code.appendChild(document.createTextNode(html));
}
```

That's should escape every html entities. If you still want to use the regexp, maybe as fallback, you can have this kind of function:

```
var escapeEntities = (function(){
    var entities = {"<" : "lt", ">" : "gt", "&" : "amp" };
    var re = new RegExp("[" + Object.keys(entities).join("") + "]", "g");

    function replaceEntities(match) {
        return match in entities ? "&" + entities[match] + ";" : match;
    }

    return function(value) {
        return value.replace(re, replaceEntities);
    }
})()
```

And then in your code:

```
code.innerHTML = escapeEntities(code.innerHTML);
```

Note that if [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is not supported you can easily use a shims (as indicated in the link); or simply replace manually the list of entities you support:

```
 var entities = {"<" : "lt", ">" : "gt", "&" : "amp" };
 var re = /[<>&]/g;
```

In that case you need to remember to add in both `entities` and `re` variables a new entity you want to support in the future; `Object.keys` just help you in maintenance.

Comment: You can style the whole block with CSS. So you can have: `code { background: silver; border: 1px solid gray }` etc.

Comment: Let me ask you this.  If I convert to text can I still style it with css?

Comment: I think I may try that then.  Thank you very much for the in depth explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use assignment:

```
code = code.replace(codeExam1, '&lt;');
code = code.replace(codeExam2, '&gt;');
```

And modify your code like this:

```
function codeDisplay ( ) {
    var codeArray = document.getElementsByTagName('code');
    var codeExam1 = new RegExp('<', 'gm');
    var codeExam2 = new RegExp('>', 'gm');

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < codeArray.length ; ++i ){
        var code = codeArray[i].innerHTML;
        code.replace(codeExam1, '&lt;');
        code.replace(codeExam2, '&gt;');
        codeArray[i].innerHTML = code; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this by loading it in the body onLoad attribute but it still does not work.

Comment: I think the problem is that'`document.getElementsByTagName('code')`' returns array,so you need to use `document.getElementsByTagName('code')[0]` instead.

Comment: Or if you have multiple 'code' element , use loop to replace contents of all those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Replace returns a new string containing the result. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for example.
To actually replace the contents of `code` you code has to look like this:

```
function codeDisplay ( ) {
  var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML;

  var codeExam1 = new RegExp('<', 'gm');
  var codeExam2 = new RegExp('>', 'gm');

  code = code.replace( codeExam1, '&lt;');
  code = code.replace(codeExam2, '&gt;');

  document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML = code;
}
```

Or a shorter version (could be even shorter, but in my opinion just at the cost of readability):

```
function codeDisplay ( ) {
  var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML;

  code = code.replace( /</gm , '&lt;' )
             .replace( />/gm, '&gt;' );

  document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML = code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function codeDisplay ( ) {
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML;
  s = s.replace(/\</g,'&lt;');
  s = s.replace(/\>/g,'&gt;');
  document.getElementsByTagName('code').innerHTML = s;
}
```